# After removing the Sequential from a convolutional network I get: "TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, siamese-network

I'm newbie with Python.

I had this code:

```
def build_base_network(input_shape):

    seq = Sequential()

    nb_filter = [6, 12]
    kernel_size = 3


    #convolutional layer 1
    seq.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter[0], kernel_size, kernel_size, input_shape=input_shape,
                          border_mode='valid', dim_ordering='th'))
    seq.add(Activation('relu'))
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
    seq.add(Dropout(.25))

    #convolutional layer 2
    seq.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter[1], kernel_size, kernel_size, border_mode='valid', dim_ordering='th'))
    seq.add(Activation('relu'))
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th')) 
    seq.add(Dropout(.25))

    #flatten 
    seq.add(Flatten())
    seq.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.1))
    seq.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    return seq


"""Next, we feed the image pair, to the base network, which will return the embeddings that is, feature vectors:"""

input_dim = x_train.shape[2:]
img_a = Input(shape=input_dim)
img_b = Input(shape=input_dim)
base_network = build_base_network(input_dim)
feat_vecs_a = base_network(img_a)
feat_vecs_b = base_network(img_b)
```

And I update the network to the latest Keras API and remove it the `Sequential`:

```
def build_base_network(input_shape):

    inputs = Input(shape = input_shape)

    nb_filter = [6, 12]
    kernel_size = 3
    conv1 = Conv2D(nb_filter[0], (kernel_size, kernel_size), activation='relu', padding="valid", data_format='channels_first')(inputs)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(.25)(pool1)

    #convolutional layer 2
    conv2 = Conv2D(nb_filter[1], (kernel_size, kernel_size), activation='relu', padding="valid", data_format="channels_first")(drop1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first")(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(.25)(pool2)

    #flatten 
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(drop2)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.1)(dense1)
    dense2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(drop3)

    return dense2

"""Next, we feed the image pair, to the base network, which will return the embeddings that is, feature vectors:"""

input_dim = x_train.shape[2:]
img_a = Input(shape=input_dim)
img_b = Input(shape=input_dim)
base_network = build_base_network(input_dim)
feat_vecs_a = base_network(img_a)
feat_vecs_b = base_network(img_b)
```

And now I get the following error on this line `feat_vecs_a = base_network(img_a)`:

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

How can I fix this error?

I'm implementing a `Siamese network using this [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/02.%20Face%20and%20Audio%20Recognition%20using%20Siamese%20Networks/2.4%20Face%20Recognition%20Using%20Siamese%20Network.ipynb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you are in face returning a Tensor instead of a model. 
Instead of Sequential use Model to wrap your Tensors.

This should do the trick:

```
def build_base_network(input_shape):

    inputs = Input(shape = input_shape)

    nb_filter = [6, 12]
    kernel_size = 3
    conv1 = Conv2D(nb_filter[0], (kernel_size, kernel_size), activation='relu', padding="valid", data_format='channels_first')(inputs)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(.25)(pool1)

    #convolutional layer 2
    conv2 = Conv2D(nb_filter[1], (kernel_size, kernel_size), activation='relu', padding="valid", data_format="channels_first")(drop1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first")(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(.25)(pool2)

    #flatten 
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(drop2)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.1)(dense1)
    dense2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(drop3)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense2)
    return model
```